# How to sort an HTML table?

Tags: html, sorting, colors

I am not at all an HTML expert.   I program microcontrollers and got off onto a tangent.

I created an html doc to show a table of microcontroller registers, register addresses and register descriptions.  I created a table with 3 columns - and about 120 rows.   Some of the register addresses are bit addressable - if their addresses end in 0 or 8.

I wanted to highlight these 'special' register addresses - by showing them in red.  So, in the table cells with a register address ending in 0 or 8, I use ""  and "" to surround the address value.

My table has 3 columns, Register, Address, and Description.  Then one row might look like

"ACC       0xE0        Accumulator".

I got my table all done and it looks great.   Then I got the idea that I want to be able to sort the table on any column.   For example, if I click on "Address" I want the table to re-display and sort by the values in that column.

I searched, and found a way to do it.  It works by having a "sort" button - click on that and it re-displays sort on the first column values.   I implemented a simple version of it and got it working.  I then changed it to instead sort on the second column when the "sort" button was clicked.

That didn't exactly work .... because of all those "" whatevers.

The example I copied from his here:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sort_table

Is there anything 'simple' I can do to use this method - but still be able have certain entries in the Address column be shown red ?

I should probably stick to programming microcontrollers, but I like a challenge.

Comment: Hello Alan and welcome to Stackoverflow. Here on SO you should always include the least amount of code in your question to reproduce your issue. Please update your question with any relevant code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I don't know what you mean by, "I use "" and "" to surround the address value." LIke `""0xE0""`? See previous comment. Just add 2 rows that could be sorted.

Comment: 3 rows: <tr> <td>ACC        </td>  <td><font color="Red">0xE0     </font></td>   <td>Accumulator                                </td>  </tr>
<tr> <td>ADC0CF     </td>  <td>0xBC      </td>   <td>ADC0 Configuration                         </td>  </tr>
<tr> <td>ADC0CN     </td>  <td><font color="Red">0xE8     </font></td>   <td>ADC0 Control                               </td>  </tr>

Answer (score 2):

sample code for sort on a selected column,
that's **free**...

```js
const
  myButtonSort  = document.querySelector('#my-button-sort')
, colSelector   = document.querySelector('#sel-col')
, myTable_tBody = document.querySelector('#my-table > tbody')
  ;
myButtonSort.onclick = _ =>
  {
  let col = parseInt(colSelector.value ); 
  [...myTable_tBody.querySelectorAll('tr')]
    .map(row=>({row, str:row.cells[col].textContent }))
    .sort((a,b)=>a.str.localeCompare(b.str))
    .forEach(el=>
      {
      myTable_tBody.appendChild(el.row)
      })
  }
```

```css
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  }
td,th  {
  padding    : .2em .8em;
  border     : 1px solid darkblue;
  }
thead {
  background : lightseagreen ;
  }
```

```html
<select id="sel-col">
  <option value="0">column x</option>
  <option value="1">column y</option>
</select>

<button id="my-button-sort">sort</button>

<table id="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr> <th>x</th> <th>y</th> </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> <td>aa</td><td> 1 </td></tr>
    <tr> <td>zz</td><td> 2 </td></tr>
    <tr> <td>ee</td><td> 3 </td></tr>
    <tr> <td>cc</td><td> 4 </td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Ascending and descending sort example:

```js
const myArray = 
  [ { worth: '100',  name: 'jessca', reason: 'money', email: 'j@gmail.com',  number: '4456',  instagram: 'hvg_ujh', tiktok: 'hhgh.thg' } 
  , { worth: '265',  name: 'e',      reason: 'money', email: 'e@gmail.com',  number: '3456',  instagram: 'hvg_ujh', tiktok: 'hhgh.thg' } 
  , { worth: '6000', name: 'ssica',  reason: 'sex',   email: 's@gmail.com',  number: '0456',  instagram: 'hvg_ujh', tiktok: 'hhgh.thg' } 
  , { worth: '855',  name: 'sica',   reason: 'sex',   email: 'ss@gmail.com', number: '9456',  instagram: 'hvg_ujh', tiktok: 'hhgh.thg' } 
  , { worth: '8679', name: 'ica',    reason: 'sex',   email: 'i@gmail.com',  number: '0756',  instagram: 'hvg_ujh', tiktok: 'hhgh.thg' } 
  , { worth: '1',    name: 'ca',     reason: 'money', email: 'c@gmail.com',  number: '14856', instagram: 'hvg_ujh', tiktok: 'hhgh.thg' } 
  ] 
const
  t_Head      = document.querySelector('#myTable thead')
, t_Head_THs  = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable thead tr th')
, th_list     = [...t_Head_THs].map( TH => TH.dataset.column)
, t_Body      = document.querySelector('#myTable tbody')
, sortOrder   = [ 'none' ,'asc', 'desc' ]
, sortType    = { worth: 'num', name:'str', reason:'str', email:'str', number:'num', instagram:'str', tiktok:'str' }
, sortProcess =
  { 'asc:num'  : (a,b) => +a.str - +b.str
  , 'desc:num' : (a,b) => +b.str - +a.str
  , 'asc:str'  : (a,b) => a.str.localeCompare(b.str)
  , 'desc:str' : (a,b) => b.str.localeCompare(a.str)
  };
myArray.forEach( row =>
  {
  let TR = t_Body.insertRow()
  for (col of th_list)
    TR.insertCell().textContent = row[col] 
  })
t_Head.onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('th')) return
  
  let
    dataOrder = sortOrder[(sortOrder.indexOf(target.dataset.order) +1 )% sortOrder.length]
  , dataType  = sortType[target.dataset.column]
    ;
  t_Head_THs.forEach( TH => { TH.dataset.order = (TH===target) ? dataOrder : 'none' })

  if (dataOrder !== 'none')
    {
    [...t_Body.querySelectorAll('tr')]
    .map     ( row => ({row, str:row.cells[target.cellIndex].textContent }))
    .sort    ( sortProcess[`${dataOrder}:${dataType}`])
    .forEach ( elm => t_Body.appendChild(elm.row ))
    }
  }
```

```css
body { 
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 16px;
  }
table {
  border-collapse  : separate;
  border-spacing   : 1px;
  background-color : darkblue;
  margin           : 1em; 
  }
th, td {
  border     : none;
  background : whitesmoke;
  padding    : .3em .4em;
  }
th {
  background-color : #76ced1;
  white-space      : nowrap;
  cursor           : pointer;
  }
th::before {
  content        : attr(data-column) ' ';
  text-transform : capitalize;
  }
th[data-order=asc]::after  { content : '\25B2'; }
th[data-order=desc]::after { content : '\25BC'; }
th[data-order=none]::after { content : '\25B2'; color:transparent; }  /* get the same width */
```

```html
<table  id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-column="worth"     data-order="none"></th>
      <th data-column="name"      data-order="none"></th>
      <th data-column="reason"    data-order="none"></th>
      <th data-column="email"     data-order="none"></th>
      <th data-column="number"    data-order="none"></th>
      <th data-column="instagram" data-order="none"></th>
      <th data-column="tiktok"    data-order="none"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started:

```js
const table = document.getElementById("test"),
      th = test.querySelectorAll("th"),
      sortDefault = 0, //default sorted column number
      orderDefault = 0; //default order: 0 = ascending, 1 = descending

table.dataset.sort = sortDefault;
table.dataset.order = orderDefault;

/* add click listeners on table headers */
for(let i = 0; i < th.length; i++)
{
  th[i].addEventListener("click", e =>
  {
    /* if this column was sorted, change it's order */
    if (+table.dataset.sort == e.target.cellIndex)
      table.dataset.order = +table.dataset.order ? 0 : 1;

    /* tell table which column is currently sorted */
    table.dataset.sort = e.target.cellIndex;

    sortColumn();
  });
}

populateTable(); //fill table with random data
sortColumn(); //initial sort of the table

function sortColumn()
{
  const rows = Array.from(table.children);
  rows.splice(0, 1); //remove header from the list
  rows.sort((a, b) => 
  {
    a = a.children[table.dataset.sort].textContent;
    b = b.children[table.dataset.sort].textContent;

    a = a.replace(/\W/g, ""); //remove non alphanumerical characters
    b = b.replace(/\W/g, ""); //remove non alphanumerical characters

    a = a.replace(/0x[a-fA-F0-9]+/, n => Number(n)); //convert 0xHEX to decimal
    b = b.replace(/0x[a-fA-F0-9]+/, n => Number(n)); //convert 0xHEX to decimal

    return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'})
  });

  if (+table.dataset.order)
    rows.reverse();

  for(let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
  {
    table.appendChild(rows[i]);
  }
}


function populateTable()
{
  for(let i = 0, _tr = document.createElement("tr"), _td = document.createElement("td"); i < 10; i++)
  {
    const tr = _tr.cloneNode(true);
    let td = _td.cloneNode(true);
    td.textContent = "reg " + rand(0, 199);
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = _td.cloneNode(true);
    td.textContent = "address 0x" + rand(0, 255).toString(16);
    if (rand(0,1))
      td.textContent = td.textContent.replace(/ (.*)/, ' "$1"');
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = _td.cloneNode(true);
    td.textContent = "desc " + rand(0, 99999).toString(16);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
  function rand(min, max)
  {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
}
```

```css
#test
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#test tr td
{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#test td
{
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}
#test th
{
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#test th:after
{
  visibility: hidden;
}
#test[data-order="0"] th:after
{
  content: "▲";
}
#test[data-order="1"] th:after
{
  content: "▼";
}
#test[data-sort="0"] th:nth-child(1):after,
#test[data-sort="1"] th:nth-child(2):after,
#test[data-sort="2"] th:nth-child(3):after
{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<table id="test">
  <tr>
    <th>Register</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```